# "?n" appended to URLs... why? How do I prevent this?

Tags: 7, theming, caching, wysiwyg

When CKEditor references my theme's stylesheet (as well as other resources), it appends `?n` to the path. Here's a screenshot from Chrome's web inspector (see highlights):

[image: This is from the <code><iframe></code> that loads in CKEditor's editing box]

(This is from the `<iframe>` that loads in CKEditor's editing box)

As far as I can tell, that `?n` is preventing CKEditor from loading the most current version of the stylesheet. When I remove `?n` (in the web inspector), the latest version loads.

So what is `?n` and how do I force it to use the most current version? I've tried flushing caches, but to no avail. It must be some kind of versioning thing?

Comment: Using [AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/) is a must for D6 sites. Using it should help a lot in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, @mikeytown2! This is a D7 site though.

Comment: The reason I guessed D6 is because [_drupal_flush_css_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_flush_css_js/6) is used to output 1 character; see [drupal_get_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_css/6) about 15 lines down.

In D7 the  [_drupal_flush_css_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_flush_css_js/7) function is time based and all characters are used in [drupal_pre_render_styles](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_styles/7)

Comment: @mikeytown2 That makes sense. Interestingly, I just checked in on things  (a few hours after posting) and the CSS file is now outputting the most current version. You're right, it must be time based.

Comment: What combination of modules are used to generate this iframe?

Comment: @mikeytown2 Just CKEditor.